# Migrating from Woocommerce Subscriptions to Civicrm memberships

Tags: stripe

I have just built a new membership system in civicrm and need to import membership details from a woocommerce subscription system. That part is fine.

The majority of payments are monthly subscriptions in stripe.

What do I need to add to the civicrm database to get the membership status to be linked to the existing recurring payment?

I have done a manual test.

I have set the:
civicrm_stripe_customers
Customer number (cus_xxxxxxxxxx)
the civi_membership record

and the civicrm_contribution_recur record (with the sub_xxxxxxxxxxxx number in both the processor_id and trxn_id fields.

I am missing something as even though the payments are going through stripe fine.